# Will the quality of my JPEG images taken by my iPhone deteriorate if I rotate than on my Mac?

Tags: photos

Can I safely rotate JPEG images on my MacBook or would this be lossy?

Answer (score 1):

Using `Preview.app`, the rotation applied is not lossless. You need to use a special tool that will either add an EXIF rotation header (which is then applied only on display) or simply keeps the encoding coefficients constant, but shifts them accordingly. One tool that supports this that has a UI is [Xee](https://theunarchiver.com/xee), on the commandline you could use `jpegtran` or `imagemagick`.

Answer (score 0):

I would of thought that any differences would be negligible however:

Create a copy of your picture then rotate that, compare file sizes / image quality after.

JPEG is already a lossy compression format in either case.

Comment: This does not answer the question, I guess.